# lodash.template with async data

Tags: javascript, lodash

I really like the [_.template](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#template) function and I use it to allow the user to type in variables in his text which I later use to replace for some data.

The only problem is that I need to collect all optional variables data prior calling the compiled template function and this process can take some time that in some cases can be redundant as the user will not always use all optional variables.

for example, let's say the user sends a string like:

`ZimGil is <%= age %> and his favorite language is <%= language %>`

I need to have the `age` and `language` variables but I don't need to have the `phone` variable which take some redundant time to get.

Trying to figure out a way to evaluate async functions in the template based on the variables used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to get all variable names.

You need to follow what lodash allows for variables to get all of them. See comments next to each part of the pattern for an explanation.

**TL;DR:** the regular expression is `/\<\%[=|-]?(?:[\s]|if|\()*(.+?)(?:[\s]|\)|\{)*\%\>/g` (without the string escapes).

```
function getTemplateVariables(template) {
  // making sure the template is a string
  template = template || '';

  const pattern = [
    '<%[=|-]?', // look for opening tag (<%, <%=, or <%-)
    '(?:[\\s]|if|\\()*', // accept any space after opening tag and before identifier
    '(.+?)', // capture the variable name (`luigi` in <%= luigi %>)
    '(?:[\\s]|\\)|\\{)*', // accept any space after identifier and before closing tag
    '%>' // look for closing tag
  ].join('');

  const regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');

  const matches = [];

  let match;
  while (match = regex.exec(template)) {
    matches.push(match[1])
  }

  return _.uniq(matches);
}
```

[`_.uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniq) is being used to remove repeated variables.

#### Changing the template function in lodash

You can override the template function in lodash using [**mixin**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mixin) and also return the variables:

```
const originLodashTemplate = _.template;

_.mixin({
  getTemplateVariables, // <-- you can use this on it's own
  template: (...args) => { // <-- or together
    const variables = _.getTemplateVariables(args[0]);
    const template = originLodashTemplate (...args);
    return {
      variables,
      template
    };
  }
});
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
const templateObj = _.template(
  "ZimGil is <%= age %> and his favorite language is <%= language %>"
);

console.log(templateObj.variables);
// will print ["age","language"]
console.log(templateObj.template({ age: "over 5000 years old", language: "turtlese" }));
// will print 'ZimGil is over 5000 years old and his favorite language is turtlese'
```

#### Async Example

```
(async () => {
  const templateObj = _.template(
    "ZimGil is <%= age %> and his favorite language is <%= language %>"
  );
  
  const templateData = {};
  for (const variable of templateObj.variables) {
    const asyncResult = await mapToAsyncCall(variable);
    templateData[variable] = asyncResult;
  }

  // this data will only contain existing variables
  templateObj.template(templateData);
  })();
```

#### Working Example

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/c8ed4feb5c4d7a3b3b3db75304d85f03?editors=0010) with an example of all of this working.

#### NOTICE

- Even though I'm pretty sure overriding `_.template` is safe (don't think it's being used with the global pointer from inside lodash), it might not be and you might want to give the mixin function a different name!
- This won't cover advanced code injection like `_.template('<% _.forEach(users, function(user) { %><li><%- user %></li><% }); %>');`. you need to add the words you plan to allow to the regex in order to support more code injections that recognize variables. Right now, it only covers `if` statements, but more can be added in the "after opening tag and before" regex above. A way to do this completely (but this is **WAY** more complicated), is changing the original source code for `_.template` to actually return the variables and overriding it with the new code. This will support all code injections that lodash supports out of the box.

Comment: `console.log(templateObj.variables);` doesn't work. `variables` is an unknown key

Comment: @Pian0_M4n I need more info than that to be able to help :-) where did you try to add a console log? how did you use the given functions?